# How can I get bash in windows 10 open to a /home/user account?

Tags: windows-10, bash

I created a /home/user account.  How do I now make bash open to that directory when I boot into bash on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do so you need to edit the .bashrc file.

Solution 1 :
open the file   `$HOME/.bashrc` 
and then add

```
cd /home/user_account
```

Solution 2 :

excute  `sh -c 'cd /home/user_account; exec "${SHELL:-sh}"'`

Comment: Solution one works for booting into my /home/user directory.  Now I have the problem that the user is still root.  What I see on the screen is "root@STANSTOY:/home/wojowhiskey#".  What can I do to make the user "wojowhiskey"?

Comment: I did manage for a superficial change by adding "su wojowhiskey" to $HOME/.bashrc file.